# Display multiple images in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can I display an image (photo.jpg for example) n times with n given in props in Reactjs? if so how can I do it?

```
function Card(props) {
  for (let i = 0; i < props.rating; i++) {
    <img className="star" src={star} alt="me"></img>;
  }
    // this is incomplete or wrong 
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="rating">
        <h3 className="rating__text">Rating:</h3>
        //here I want to add imgs of stars
      </div>
      <div className="personna">
        <img className="personna__img" src={props.personnaImg} alt="me"></img>
        <h3 className="personna__name">{props.personnaName}t</h3>
      </div>
      <p>review text</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will generate an array of `props.rating` length. Map over it and return the images.

```js
<div className="rating">
  <h3 className="rating__text">Rating:</h3>
  {Array.from({ length: props.rating }, (_, i) => i).map((i) => (
    <img className="star" src={star} alt="me" key={`rating-img-${i}`} />
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: please in (_,i), what does _ stands for ?

Comment: It is indicating a unused variable, since we create an empty array the value will be `null`. The `i` is the index which we fill the array with